# Running dbt results in `Profile() takes no arguments` error

Tags: python, dbt

When I run dbt run I get:

```sh
Encountered an error:
Profile() takes no arguments
```

Running `dbt debug` shows:

```sh
Running with dbt=0.20.0
dbt version: 0.20.0
python version: 3.9.7
python path: /home/USER/.pyenv/versions/3.9.7/bin/python3.9
os info: Linux-5.10.68-1-MANJARO-x86_64-with-glibc2.33
Using profiles.yml file at /home/USER/dbt/profiles.yml
Using dbt_project.yml file at /home/USER/dbt/project/dbt_project.yml

Encountered an error:
object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

The profile and project yaml work for other people, so I guess it is something wrong on my system, but don't know what could be different.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by using Python 3.9.7 and the solution is to downgrade to 3.9.6 as per this issue: https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt/issues/3843